# System hangs often after upgrading to 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

**How** to check **what** process is slowing my system?
I tried solutions shared on some related threads but none of them resolved this issue. Does my hardware matched the minimum requirement of 14.04LTS?

System Details are:-

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Memory: 1.8GB
Processor: Intel Core i3-3110M CPU @ 2.4GHz x 4
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM3.4, 256 bits)
OS 64-bit
Disk 484.8GB
```

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: 
Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0553
        Kernel Driver in use: i915
```

Comment: `top` can be used to find processes that ask for lots of resources. Run it in a tty and check it when the system is slow.

Answer (score 0):

1.8gb memory is not suitable for 64bit systems. You should strongly consider increasing your memory or reverting back to a 32bit OS.

If neither one of them is not possible, you can try to enable [Zswap](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enable-zswap-to-increase-performance/11302) on your system. My guess is, your system runs out of memory and starts writing on swap, at which point you face those slowdowns.

Comment: It seems **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** does not support ZSWAP. I ran the command as mentioned in step 1 defined in the [link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/enable-zswap-to-increase-performance/11302) you shared.

Comment: @ysaini Bummer. I thought it was supported in 14.04. You can try another alternative ZRAM by this command ```sudo apt-get install zram-config```.

You can take [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/speed#TOC-Only-768-MB-RAM-or-less:-enable-zRam) as a reference.

Comment: I have enabled the ZRAM. The link you shared talks about couple of issues that can be observed after installing ZRAM. I will share my feedback/observations after couple of days. Thanks!